# Linq to SQL Causes Brittle Coupling to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop, linq-to-sql

Linq to SQL is truncating a decimal type instead of rounding it. Apparently this is [expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572765/279516). In order to get around this, I'm rounding the value in my C# code. For example, say I have this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal SomeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The database type for SomeNumber is decimal(9,5). This precision was a business decision made by the customer.

If SomeNumber is .00079547 in code, L2S truncates it to .00079 when sending the query to SQL Server. What I need to happen is for the number to round to .00080. In order to do that, I have this method in my code:

```
private static decimal RoundToMatchSqlServerPrecision(decimal numberToRound)
{
    const int roundingPlaces = 5;

    return Math.Round(numberToRound, roundingPlaces);
}
```

As you can see, I now have C# code that is tightly coupled to the type in the DB. If we change the type in the DB, we'll have to remember to change this code, and that's not cool. I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way?
2. If I have to put this rounding logic in code, does it make sense for it to go in the business logic layer or the data access layer?

Comment: *"This precision was a business decision made by the customer."* Perhaps it's the case then that this important domain behaviour should not be the responsibility of the database?

Comment: Even if the responsibility shouldn't be on the DB, we still have to pick the number of decimal places to use, then round properly when saving to the DB.

Comment: What I was trying to say was, if it's domain behavior, the rule should be encoded into the domain model as an invariant. It's nothing to do with the database schema as such. You hinted at this in the last sentence of your question.

Comment: So does that mean you think it should just be rounded in a business logic class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Is there a better way?

I'm afraid not. The problem is related with `SqlCommand`s decision to execute parametrized queries as a remote procedure call (RPC). Which means that it executes an `sp_executesql` command in stead of a straight SQL command ([here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bindeshv/archive/2010/07/13/ef-query-execution-pattern-usage-of-sp-executesql-vs-direct-execution-of-sql-statement.aspx) where I got this information).

I've found out that the parameters in an `sp_executesql` are always truncated (not rounded) to the precision of the datatype they are associated with. I don't know why, it seems to be inconsistent with assigning a value with greater precision to a decimal in T-SQL, which causes the value to be rounded:

```sql
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF -- is default
DECLARE @p1 Decimal(16,6) = 32.6607647
PRINT @p1
-- result: 32.660765
```

So I don't see any other work around than doing the rounding yourself. (As an aside, the default rounding method in .Net is banker's rounding. You may want to use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.)

---

> 2.business logic layer or the data access layer?

In my opinion this is so closely related to the data layer implementation (it may not be a point with other database vendors!) that I would not let this peculiarity bleed into the business layer. Moreover, in the business layer you probably want to keep intermediary calculation results with maximum precision. Only when it comes to storing values, rounding comes in play.

Comment: +1 I like the point about other DB vendors possibly not having this issue. I would tend to agree that this rounding belongs in the data layer, but my coworkers suggested otherwise. That's why I wanted to find out what others thought. Thanks!